# The parameters dictionary contains a null entry?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have this MVC web app. And I'm working on getting some records. However, apparently the system is not seeing one of my parameters. The code for this project is as follows:

The Model:

```
public class AuditInfo
{
    public List<AuditRecord> AuditRecords { get; set; }
    public int PageIndex { get; set; }
}
```

Very simple model with a list of audit records, and a PageIndex for the page number.

The Controller:
On the initial pull for the first set of 100 data entries for these records, it calls this method:

```
public ActionResult AuditHistory(String username)
    {
        SearchInfo searchInfo = new SearchInfo { UserName = username };

        User user = UserManager.GetUser(username);
        var filteredApps = UserManager.GetUserAppListFromAuditRecord(user);
        List<ApplicationListView> appList = filteredApps.Select(Mapper.DynamicMap<ApplicationListView>).ToList();
        List<SelectListItem> appsList = appList.Select(appItem => new SelectListItem
        {
            Text = appItem.Name,
            Value = appItem.ID.ToString()
        }).ToList();
        appsList.Insert(0, new SelectListItem { Text = String.Empty, Value = String.Empty });
        ViewData["UserAppList"] = appsList;
        var uName = searchInfo.UserName;
        ViewData["UName"] = uName;
        AuditInfo auditInfo = _userHelper.GetAuditInfo(searchInfo);
        Response.CacheControl = "no-cache";
        Response.AddHeader("Pragma", "no-cache");
        Response.Expires = -1;

        return PartialView(auditInfo);
    }
```

On the next pull, it calls this method:

```
public ActionResult GetRows(String username, int? selectedAppId, int pageIndex)
    {
        SearchInfo searchInfo = new SearchInfo { UserName = username };
        AuditInfo auditRecord = _userHelper.GetAuditInfo(searchInfo, pageIndex, selectedAppId);

        return PartialView("_AuditDataTable", auditRecord);
    }
```

The back end logic is all working fine because it returns the results fine, and I also have a filter in place based on a drop down list which is working fine.

In the main view I have:

```
@model Models.ViewModel.AuditInfo
@{
List<SelectListItem> userApps = (List<SelectListItem>)ViewData["UserAppList"];
var userName = ViewData["UName"].ToString();
var page = Model.PageIndex;
}


@Html.Label("Sort by Application:")
@Html.DropDownList("appID", userApps, new { id = "appID" })

@using (Ajax.BeginForm("GetRows", "User", new AjaxOptions() { InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace, UpdateTargetId = "audit_partial" }, new { id = "dropListSubmit" }))
{    
@Html.Hidden("username", userName, new { id = "user" })
@Html.Hidden("selectedAppId")
@Html.Hidden("pageIndex", Model.PageIndex)
}

<div id="audit_partial">
@Html.Partial("_AuditDataTable", Model)
</div>
@{int pageNumber = @Model.PageIndex;}
@{ if (pageNumber > 0)
{
@Ajax.ActionLink("Previous", "GetRows", "User", new AjaxOptions { InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace, UpdateTargetId = "dropListSubmit" }, new { id = "prevRecords" })
   pageNumber = @Model.PageIndex - 1;
}
}
@{ if (Model.AuditRecords.Count == 100)
{
@Ajax.ActionLink("Next", "GetRows", new { controller = "User" }, new AjaxOptions { InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace, UpdateTargetId = "audit_partial" }, new { id = "nextRecords" })
   pageNumber = @Model.PageIndex + 1;
}
}
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    $().dataTable({
        "bFilter": true,
        "bPaginate": true,
        "bLengthChange": false,
        'iDisplayLength': 100,
        "bSort": false,
        "bInfo": false,
        "sDom": "lrti"
    });

    $('#appID').change(function () {
        var appIdValue = $("#appID").val();
        $("#selectedAppId").val(appIdValue);
        $('#dropListSubmit').submit();
    });
});
</script>
```

I cannot see why it's not seeing the pageIndex. Thanks for looking!

Comment: Can you post the whole error message and indicate the line it occurs on?

Comment: The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter 'pageIndex' of non-nullable type 'System.Int32' for method 'System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult GetRows(System.String, System.Nullable`1[System.Int32], Int32)' in App.Controllers.UserController'. An optional parameter must be a reference type, a nullable type, or be declared as an optional parameter.<br>Parameter name: parameters

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this line

```
@Ajax.ActionLink("Previous", "GetRows", "User", new AjaxOptions { InsertionMode = nsertionMode.Replace, UpdateTargetId = "dropListSubmit" }, new { id = "prevRecords" })
```

no route values are provided. The same for `nextRecords`. For nullable parameters it is fine, although I don't think it is intentional, but `pageIndex` will fail. To fix this simply provide the necessary object:

```
@Ajax.ActionLink("Previous", "GetRows", "User",
                 new { pageIndex = @Model.PageIndex - 1, username = userName },
                 new AjaxOptions {
                     InsertionMode = nsertionMode.Replace,
                     UpdateTargetId = "dropListSubmit" },
                 new { id = "prevRecords" })
```

Comment: Wow. Can't believe I forgot to pass the parameters through the link. Thank you for that!